# How to access a static member from within a constructor

Tags: typescript

```
class MockFamily implements IFamily {
    static instances: MockFamily[] = [];

    constructor (nodeClass: { new (): Node; }, engine: Engine) {
        MockFamily.instances.push(this);
    }

    /* sniiiiiip */
}
```

In the above example is there any way to access the static `instances` value from within the constructor without using the actual class name?

Comment: Just curious, what problem are you trying to solve? Also I can not access it without a qualification in other methods.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve with the static instances?  This is a mock object used in an integration test to ensure that another class is properly utilizing these family objects.  Part of that involves needing to easily access the instances of the mock object that get created to ensure certain things happened.  There are other methods on this mock that are stubbed out to simply track how often they are called and a few other things allow me to easily write tests against them.  I could have used spy's from Sinon to solve the same problem for instance... I just didn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Static variables are always accessed trough the class-name. The class object acts as an object with properties. The closest you could come is maybe:

```
with (MockFamily) {
    instances.push(this);
}
```

Though I would not recommend it.

Modules are another thing though. At run-time, their contents are variables in a function scope, and can be accessed directly almost anywhere within.

```
module MyModule {
    var instances: IFamily[] = [];

    export class MockFamily implements IFamily {
        constructor (nodeClass: { new (): Node; }, engine: Engine) {
            instances.push(this);
        }

        /* sniiiiiip */
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh, i like that solution;  simple enough, why didn't I think of that? :P  Thanks for the help!